# Mdb Glasswish Websphere MQ

Tags: jms, glassfish-3, ibm-mq

I'm new in MDB and EE. Please tell me there is i'm wrong.
My app must interaction with Websphere MQ (wait a messaege in queue, do something and reply).
I'm using NetBeans 7.3 ,GlassFish 3.1, Websphere MQ 6.2, resorce adapter wmq.jmsra.rar. Interaction must be not in jms format is, only Web MQ nature.
I'm deploy adapter and create Connecton pool and Administrated Object.
In domain.xml

```
  <connector-connection-pool description="" name="cpMqAdapter" resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra" connection-definition-name="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" transaction-support="LocalTransaction">
  <property name="port" value="1414"></property>
  <property name="CCSID" value="866"></property>
  <property name="hostName" value="192.168.0.11"></property>
  <property name="queueManager" value="QM"></property>
  <property name="channel" value="SrvConn"></property>
  <property description="CLIENT - mq on other computer" name="transportType" value="CLIENT"></property>
</connector-connection-pool>


<admin-object-resource enabled="false" res-adapter="wmq.jmsra" res-type="javax.jms.Queue" description="" jndi-name="wmqJmsAOR" class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy">
  <property name="priority" value="APP"></property>
  <property name="failIfQuiesce" value="true"></property>
  <property name="baseQueueManagerName" value="QM"></property>
  <property name="CCSID" value="1208"></property>
  <property name="persistence" value="APP"></property>
  <property name="encoding" value="NATIVE"></property>
  <property name="baseQueueName" value="TEST"></property>
  <property name="targetClient" value="MQ"></property>
  <property name="expiry" value="APP"></property>
</admin-object-resource>
```

'
In netbeans i'm create EE project and message driven bean. i'm gett this code '

```
   @MessageDriven(mappedName = "wmqJmsAOR", activationConfig = {
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto- 
   acknowledge"),
   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")

 })
public class NewMessage implements MessageListener {
public NewMessage() {
    super();
    System.out.println("I created");
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    System.out.println("I'm getting message");

}
`
```

Please tell me why this MDB is not listenig a queue (i'm put test message in Websphere MQ console). May be i'm must write something in config (now project as default netbeans created).

Alexei

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?  I am running into the same issue.  I don't get any errors but it just does not receive any messages. I even put all the connection information into the admin-object properties..

Comment: @Armand Hello. No, this task was canceled. It is possible that i'm will be back later to this work

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that works. It is not the best solution but it does work extremely well.

What we have done is to create a very simple ***ActivationSpecWrapper*** class to extend the IBM ***com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl*** class. This wrapper class has one public set/get property (*asJNDI*). The purpose if the class is to read via JNDI context the Properties class defined in the App server that contains all the properties to be assigned in the activation of the MDB.

First, create the new ***ActivationSpecWrapper*** class.  you can put this in any package of your choosing.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl;

public class ActivationSpecWrapper extends ActivationSpecImpl
{

   private static final long   serialVersionUID = -529716553593856979L;

   private static final String sourceClass      = ActivationSpecWrapper.class.getName();
   private static final Logger log              = Logger.getLogger(sourceClass);

   private String              asJNDI           = null;

   public void setAsJNDI(String asJNDI)
   {
      log.config("asJNDI = " + asJNDI);
      this.asJNDI = asJNDI;

      try
      {
         final InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
         final Properties properties = (Properties) ctx.lookup(asJNDI);

         for (final Object key : properties.keySet())
         {
            try
            {
               final String value = properties.getProperty((String) key);
               final Object field = getSetter((String) key);
               if (field != null)
               {
                  if (field instanceof Field)
                  {
                     log.fine("Setting " + key + " via Field " + (String) key + " = " + value);
                     ((Field) field).set(this, value);

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     log.fine("Setting " + key + " via Method " + (String) key + " = " + value);
                     ((Method) field).invoke(this, value);
                  }
                  log.config(key + " = " + value);
               }
               else
               {
                  log.warning("Invalid ActivationSpec Field: " + key);
               }
            }
            catch (final NoSuchFieldException e)
            {
               log.throwing(sourceClass, "setAsJNDI", e);
            }

         }

      }
      catch (final Exception e)
      {
         log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error looking up " + asJNDI, e);
         return;
      }

   }

   public String getAsJNDI()
   {
      return asJNDI;
   }

   private static Object getField(String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException
   {
      return ActivationSpecWrapper.class.getField(fieldName);
   }

   private static Object getSetter(String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException
   {
      try
      {
         final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fieldName.length() + 3).append("set").append(fieldName);
         sb.setCharAt(3, Character.toUpperCase(sb.charAt(3)));

         return ActivationSpecWrapper.class.getMethod(sb.toString(), String.class);
      }
      catch (final NoSuchMethodException e)
      {
         return getField(fieldName);
      }
   }
}
```

To implement the class you just need to modify the **META-INF/ra.xml** file inside the **wmq.jmsra.rar** file.  Change the one occurrence of the ActivationSpecImpl class to your class. This will be your new incoming connection factory's ***ActivationSpecWrapper*** class that it uses. So now your wrapper class can look to the app server for the properties to use.

I do this as follows:

```
: jar -xvf wmq.jmsra.rar META-INF/ra.xml
: perl -pi -e 's/com\.ibm\.mq\.connector\.inbound\.ActivationSpecImpl/your.new.package.ActivatonSpecWrapper/g' META-INF/ra.xml
: jar -uvf wmq.jmsra.rar META-INF/ra.xml
```

Before modifying the **META-INF/ra.xml** looks like:

```
<activationspec>
   <activationspec-class>
      com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl
   </activationspec-class>
   <required-config-property>
      <config-property-name>destination</config-property-name>
   </required-config-property>
   <required-config-property>
      <config-property-name>destinationType</config-property-name>
   </required-config-property>
</activationspec>
```

After the change, the **META-INF/ra.xml** should like like:

```
<activationspec>
   <activationspec-class>
      your.new.package.ActivatonSpecWrapper
   </activationspec-class>
   <required-config-property>
      <config-property-name>destination</config-property-name>
   </required-config-property>
   <required-config-property>
      <config-property-name>destinationType</config-property-name>
   </required-config-property>
</activationspec>
```

Now you will need to add your new package to the RAR file.  It should be in standard directory structure.  like this:

```
: jar -uvf wmq.jmsra.rar your/new/package/ActivationSpecWrapper.class
```

The problem stems from IBM placing the host/port/queue manager/channel (etc.) into the activation spec instead of the administration object. It belongs in the administration object since that is the connection factory for MDB queues. IBM only allows two properties there.

Also if you are using glassfish, oracle really botched things up for MDB classes that need resource adapters, because the glassfish ***@MessageDriven*** annotation assumes the app containers default resource adapter (*OpenMQ*) for JMS. This means the vendor specific ***ActivationSpecImpl*** does not work, and thus IMB's custom parameters for host/port and other activation config properties are not supported via annotations until after the resource adaptor is switch via the **glassfish-ejb-jar.xml**.

JBoss allows for the ***@ResourceAdapter*** annotation to change the resource adapter but Glassfish only allows this via the **glassfish-ejb-jar.xml** file. And when this is used, you only need to annotate your MDB with three activation config properties (the *destinationType*). Everything else you will place in your JNDI published Properties.

The **glassfish-ejb-jar.xml** should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<glassfish-ejb-jar>

    <enterprise-beans >
        <unique-id>1</unique-id>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>MyMDB</ejb-name>
            <mdb-resource-adapter>
                <resource-adapter-mid>wmq.jmsra</resource-adapter-mid>
                <activation-config>
                    <activation-config-property>
                        <activation-config-property-name>asJNDI</activation-config-property-name>
                        <activation-config-property-value>mq/InboundMessages</activation-config-property-value>
                    </activation-config-property>
                </activation-config>
            </mdb-resource-adapter>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans> 
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

The MDB ***@MessageDriven*** annotation will look something like this:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig =
   {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/InboundMessage_queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "true") })
public class MyMDB implement MessageListener
{
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {
        // message handler code goes here...
    }
}
```

The last step to make this work, is to add the *mq/InboundMessages* properties to JDNI, to define the factory properties for the MQ listener resource.  This is how it is defined in the **domain.xml** file:

```
<custom-resource res-type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="mq/InboundMessages" factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory">
  <property name="hostName" value="mqserver"></property>
  <property name="port" value="1422"></property>
  <property name="queueManager" value="MQMNGR"></property>
  <property name="channel" value="MQMNGR.SM.S1"></property>
  <property name="transportType" value="CLIENT"></property>
</custom-resource>
```

I hope this helps. This isn't the easiest solution but it is simple enough, and once it has been established, it is very portable, and allows the app server administrator to manage the connection details to the MQ, instead of the developer.

Comment: Hello! Thank'you Armand. After one year i'm back to this work. Your answer was very helpful. I'm create glassfish-ejb-jar.xml and set a <resource-adapter-mid>wmq.jmsra</resource-adapter-mid> and <activation-config><activation-config-property> with property to MQQueueManger connection and it's working. But this solution does not love because all of the parameters contained in the descriptor. Could you tell us more about the version with Wrapper and contents in descriptor in your case.

Comment: It is worth noting, that IBM does not support Transactions in the JMS ResourceAdaptor.  Implementing support for XA-Transactions is very easy.  Just add the ***com.ibm.mqetclient.jar*** file to the RAR file, and just that easily XA Transactions are now supported by MDBs.  Also, I do all this with MQ7, but it does work with MQ6 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response